# I think my cat is scared of me

Tags: cats

So my cat likes to go outside onto the porch even though he’s an inside cat. I am rushing to get to the bus today and I try going through the back door, but my cat thinks it’s outside time so because I am also holding a guitar bag it hits him and I kind of squish him. He runs back inside and kind of hides in the hallway, when I try to come up to him he runs into my room so I just leave for school. What do I do?

Comment: If you have startled him once, don't worry about it; he'll get over it when he figures out it was an accident, and may have essentially forgotten about it by the time you read this. Cats get under foot. Cats learn not to get under foot and we learn to watch for them.